# Is there any way that I can run an unit test for a java file in python?

Tags: java, python-3.x, unit-testing

Is there any way that I can run an unit test for a java file in python? Basically I create unit test in python language. But recently, I got a project that is written in java. So, if I want to run unit test do I need learn JAVA? Or I can do it in python?

Comment: I'm sure you could hack something together... but why not just write your unit tests in Java?

Comment: actually, no on second thought it's a terrible idea. Stick to writing unit tests in the language your code base is in.

Comment: I got it. So, the best way will be learning JAVA. Thanks for your suggestions.